# How to write this SQL in MetaWhere?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, meta-where

How would I write this query using [MetaWhere](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/) (in Rails 3)?

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
INNER JOIN "friendships" friends 
   ON "users"."id" = friends."friend_id" 
INNER JOIN "friendships" inverse_friends 
   ON "users"."id" = inverse_friends."user_id" 
WHERE friends."user_id" = 4 
   AND friends."status" = 't' 
   AND inverse_friends."friend_id" = 4 
   AND inverse_friends."status" = 't'
```

I'm trying to add a method on my`User` class called `buddies` that will return both `friends` and `inverse_friends` from this [Railscast on self-referential association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association).

I'd appreciate any help!

---

EDIT: I want to be able to query on the returned set, such that I can do:

```
def is_a_buddy_of?(user)
  not self.buddies.where(:friend_id >> user.id).empty?
end
```

---

SOLUTION: Nevermind that last edit, I just modified my `is_a_buddy_of?(user)` method to this, using the `|` operator on my existing associations:

```
def is_a_buddy_of?(user)
  status = false
  self.buddies.map do |buddy|
    status = true if buddy.id == user.id
  end
  status
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you just do the following in your User model?:

```
def buddies
  inverse_friends | friends
end
```

`|` is the union operator.

Comment: I sometimes hate RoR for its simplicity. :) Thanks.

Comment: Aph, I spoke too soon... this gives me an array, not an AR::Relation. I want to be able to query on this method... (see edit above)

Comment: Wow, I really shouldn't code after nearly finishing a bottle of rather good `Terre del Negroamaro` (tasty!). I opted to stick with your union operator and adjusted my `buddies` method accordingly (see last edit above). Thanks again.